# Qt/MySQLITE errors on simple query which MySQL accepts

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I have a QSqlDatabase of QSQLITE type which give me this error

```
near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error Unable to execute statement
```

on this statement (which MySQL executes correctly)

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`fullname` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`date_of_birth` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`date_enrolled` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`current_academic_year` INT NOT NULL
)
```

I tried [changing `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `AUTOINCREMENT`](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and then to [`id NOT NULL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)but neither made any difference.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,
"fullname" TEXT NOT NULL ,
"date_of_birth" DATETIME NOT NULL ,
"date_enrolled" DATETIME NOT NULL ,
"current_academic_year" INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks. For extra credit, is there a good place where the language differences (*specifically* when compared to MySQL) are documented?

Comment: I don't know a good document that highlights the differences. But you can see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751160/mysql-and-sqlite-differences-in-sql